# OpenCV with Python error - Assertion failed ((mask.type() == CV_8UC1 || mask.type() == CV_8SC1)) in binary_op

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, webcam

I am trying to overlay an image over the webcam feed. Here's the main section of the code -

```
# Load our overlay image: glasses.png
imgGlasses = cv2.imread('1.png')
     
# Create the mask for the glasses
imgGlassesGray = cv2.cvtColor(imgGlasses, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret, orig_mask = cv2.threshold(imgGlasses, 10, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
 
# Create the inverted mask for the glasses
orig_mask_inv = cv2.bitwise_not(orig_mask)
 
# Convert glasses image to BGR
# and save the original image size (used later when re-sizing the image)
imgGlasses = imgGlasses[:,:,0:3]
origGlassesHeight, origGlassesWidth = imgGlasses.shape[:2]
    
video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = video_capture.read()

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
    for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
        #cv2.rectangle(frame,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)
            roi_gray = gray[y:y+h, x:x+w]
            roi_color = frame[y:y+h, x:x+w]
            
            eyes = eye_cascade.detectMultiScale(roi_gray)
            for (ex,ey,ew,eh) in eyes:
            cv2.rectangle(roi_color,(ex,ey),(ex+ew,ey+eh),(0,255,0),2)
                
        for (ex, ey, ew, eh) in eyes:
            glassesWidth = 3*ew
            glassesHeight = glassesWidth * origGlassesHeight / origGlassesWidth
            
            # Center the glasses on the bottom of the nose
            x1 = ex - (glassesWidth/4)
            x2 = ex + ew + (glassesWidth/4)
            y1 = ey + eh - (glassesHeight/2)
            y2 = ey + eh + (glassesHeight/2)
                     
            # Re-calculate the width and height of the glasses image
            glassesWidth = x2 - x1
            glassesHeight = y2 - y1
         
            # Re-size the original image and the masks to the glasses sizes
            # calcualted above
            glasses = cv2.resize(imgGlasses, (glassesWidth,glassesHeight), interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
            mask = cv2.resize(orig_mask, (glassesWidth,glassesHeight), interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
            mask_inv = cv2.resize(orig_mask_inv, (glassesWidth,glassesHeight), interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
         
            # take ROI for glasses from background equal to size of glasses image
            roi = roi_color[y1:y2, x1:x2]
         
                # roi_bg contains the original image only where the glasses is not
                # in the region that is the size of the glasses.
            roi_bg = cv2.bitwise_and(roi,roi,mask = mask_inv)
         
                # roi_fg contains the image of the glasses only where the glasses is
            roi_fg = cv2.bitwise_and(glasses,glasses,mask = mask)
         
                # join the roi_bg and roi_fg
            dst = cv2.add(roi_bg,roi_fg)
         
                # place the joined image, saved to dst back over the original image
            roi_color[y1:y2, x1:x2] = dst
         
            break
```

I get the following error while trying to run the program and I have no idea how to fix this -

> OpenCV Error: Assertion failed ((mask.type() == CV_8UC1 || mask.type()
> == CV_8SC1)) in binary_op, file /home/user/opencv-2.4.10/modules/core/src/arithm.cpp, line 1035
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "main_eye.py", line 86, in
>
> roi_bg = cv2.bitwise_and(roi,roi,mask = mask_inv) cv2.error: /home/user/opencv-2.4.10/modules/core/src/arithm.cpp:1035: error:
> (-215) (mask.type() == CV_8UC1 || mask.type() == CV_8SC1) in function
> binary_op

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your mask is image with 3 channels, but it should has only one channel. You can check it by using `mask.shape` - it will return tuple with dimensions of your mask. Problem is here:

```
imgGlassesGray = cv2.cvtColor(imgGlasses, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret, orig_mask = cv2.threshold(imgGlasses, 10, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
```

You are creating mask using image with 3 channels, so you mask will have 3 channels as well. Create it using single channel image (most likely you wanted to use imgGlassesGray instead of imgGlasses) - it should solve you problem.

```
imgGlassesGray = cv2.cvtColor(imgGlasses, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret, orig_mask = cv2.threshold(imgGlassesGray, 10, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
```

Comment: Thanks a million! That worked. I've got a lot of reading to do on masks and other image manipulations. Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks! this was helpful for me too